# KDB+/Q: Custom min max scaler

Tags: kdb

Im trying to implement a custom min max scaler in kdb+/q. I have taken note of the implementation located in the [ml package](https://code.kx.com/v2/ml/toolkit/utilities/preproc/#mlminmaxscaler) however I'm looking to be able to scale data between a custom range i.e. 0 and 255. What would be an efficient implementation of min max scaling in kdb+/q?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work nicely

```
minmaxCustom:{[l;u;x]l + (u - l) *  (x-mnx)%max[x]-mnx:min x}
```

As petty as it sounds, it is my strong recommendation that you **do not** follow through with Shehir94 solution for a custom minimum value. Applying a maximum to get a starting range, it will mess with the original distribution. A custom minmax scaling should be a simple linear transformation on a standard 0-1 minmax transformation.

```
X' = a + bX
```

For example, to get a custom scaling of 10-255, that would be a `b=245` and `a=10`, we would expect the new mean to follow this formula and the standard deviation to only be a Multiplicative, but applying lower bound messes with this, for example.

```
q)dummyData:10000?100.0
q)stats:{`transform`minVal`maxVal`avgVal`stdDev!(x;min y;max y; avg y; dev y)}
q)minmax255roundlb:{[sf;lb;x]lb|sf*(x-mnx)%max[x]-mnx:min x}[255;10]
q)minmaxCustom:{[l;u;x]l + (u - l) *  (x-mnx)%max[x]-mnx:min x}
q)res:stats'[`orig`lb`linear;(dummyData;minmax255roundlb dummyData;minmaxCustom[10;255;dummyData])]
q)res
transform minVal     maxVal   avgVal   stdDev
-----------------------------------------------
orig      0.02741043 99.98293 50.21896 28.92852
lb        10         255      128.2518 73.45999
linear    10         255      133.024  70.9064

// The transformed average should roughly be 
q)10 + ((255-10)%100)*49.97936
132.4494
// The transformed std devaition should roughly be
q)2.45*28.92852
70.87487
```

To answer the comment, this could be applied over a large number of coluwould be applied to a table in the following manner

```
q)n:10000
q)tab:([]sym:n?`3;col1:n?100.0)
q)multiColApply:{[tab;scaler;colList]flip ft,((),colList)!((),scaler each (ft:flip tab)[colList])}
q)multiColApply[tab;minmaxCustom[10;20];`col1`col2]
sym col1     col2     col3    
------------------------------
cag 13.78461 10.60606 392.7524
goo 15.26201 16.76768 517.0911
eoh 14.05111 19.59596 515.9796
kbc 13.37695 19.49495 406.6642
mdc 10.65973 12.52525 178.0839
odn 16.24697 17.37374 301.7723
ioj 15.08372 15.05051 785.033 
mbc 16.7268  20       534.7096
bhj 12.95134 18.38384 711.1716
gnf 19.36005 15.35354 411.597 
gnd 13.21948 18.08081 493.1835
khi 12.11997 17.27273 578.5203
```

Comment: Great thanks, How would you efficiently apply this function to a table?

Comment: It will handle vectors nicely so be very easy to use with a table, I'll add an example

Comment: Sorry to ask again Callum, Thanks for your edit, I can see how this would be efficient for applying to a column, my question/comment above relates to how you could apply this to multiple columns simultaneuously? how could you most efficiently do this? thanks

Comment: Aside from just manually applying it to each column? Do you have a very large list of columns to work with?

Comment: I've applied a quick example, it can likely be improved further

Comment: Roughly 200 columns the single column method causes a bottleneck, thinking of implementing your solution in parallel, what would in your opinion be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the bottleneck time or memory?

Comment: the time it would take to iteratively scale all columns, hence parralelism

Comment: You would need to thread it as a column per thread, so `scaler peach`. A performance boost will only occur if the cost of serialization is smaller than the gain in concurrent performance, i.e., the columns need to be pretty large

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the link to [github](https://github.com/kxsystems/ml/blob/master/util/preproc.q) on the page you referenced it looks like you may be able to define a function like so:
`minmax255:{[sf;x]sf*(x-mnx)%max[x]-mnx:min x}[255]`
Where sf is your scaling factor (here given by 255).

```
q)minmax255 til 10
0 28.33333 56.66667 85 113.3333 141.6667 170 198.3333 226.6667 255
```

If you don't like decimals you could round to the nearest whole number like:

```
q)minmax255round:{[sf;x]floor 0.5+sf*(x-mnx)%max[x]-mnx:min x}[255]
q)minmax255round til 10
0 28 57 85 113 142 170 198 227 255
```

(logic here is if I have a number like 1.7, add .5, and floor I'll wind up with 2, whereas if I had a number like 1.2, add .5, and floor I'll end up with 1)

If you don't want to start at 0 you could use | which takes the max of it's left and right arguments

```
q)minmax255roundlb:{[sf;lb;x]lb|floor sf*(x-mnx)%max[x]-mnx:min x}[255;10]
q)minmax255roundlb til 10
10 28 56 85 113 141 170 198 226 255
```

Where I'm using lb to mean 'lower bound'

If you want to apply this to a table you could use

```
q)show testtab:([]a:til 10;b:til 10)
a b
---
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
q)update minmax255 a from testtab
a        b
----------
0        0
28.33333 1
56.66667 2
85       3
113.3333 4
141.6667 5
170      6
198.3333 7
226.6667 8
255      9
```